# Upgrade Monit 5.25.3 to 5.26 ... configure/make install

Tags: monit

I have installed Monit like described here:

https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Installation

Now i want to upgrade. What is the right/best way ? Do this process again ?

Thx for help
RIchard

Answer (score 0):

You can use [monit precompiled binary](https://mmonit.com/monit/#download) instead of building from source.

#### 1. Check current monit

```
root@x-arm:~# monit --version
This is Monit version 5.25.1

root@x-arm:~# which monit
/usr/bin/monit
```

#### 2. Download precompiled binary, based on your arch

```
root@x-arm:~# wget https://mmonit.com/monit/dist/binary/5.26.0/monit-5.26.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz

root@x-arm:~# tar zxvf monit-5.26.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
```

#### 3. Replace with latest version

```
root@x-arm:~# cp monit-5.26.0/bin/monit /usr/bin/monit

root@x-arm:~# monit --version
This is Monit version 5.26.0
Built with ssl, with ipv6, with compression, with pam and with large files
Copyright (C) 2001-2019 Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
```

Comment: Which binary is the right for a RPI-3B (Stretch) ? thx Richard

Comment: Pi 3 Model B is using arm BCM2837 64bit CPU, so binary will be `linux-arm64`